# Generating a variable frequency sine wave in Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency, trigonometry

Title kind of says it all and it seems straightforward, but I am having difficulties.

I would like to create a sine wave that decays in frequency exponentially at a power that I input.  I have tried a bunch of different things and I either get gibberish, or what I believe is called an acoustic beat?

Gibberish example

In this example the array multiplier goes from 1->4.  When I plot cos(70000000*t) and cos(4*70000000*t) both plots look fine, but the plot in the code below just looks like noise.

```
t = 1:.0000000004:1.0000004;
multiplier = linspace(1,2,1001).^-2;
reference_signal = cos(700000000*t.*multiplier);
plot(reference_signal)
```

Beat Example https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfZnE.jpg

```
t = 1:.0000000004:1.0000004;
mult = linspace(1,3,1001);
plot(cos(700000000*t.*mult));
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might create an array that represents a sinewave that is smoothly decaying in frequency exponentially?

Many Thanks

Comment: It seems like changing my t value 
from t = 1:.0000000004:1.0000004;
to   t = 0:.0000000004:0.0000004;

fixed it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is one of sampling - your sampling frequency is too low for the signal you are trying to represent.

I suggest that you debug by explicitly computing

```
freq = 7E8/(2*pi);
t = 1 + linspace(0, 4E-7, 1001);
multiplier = linspace(1,2,1001).^2;
omega_t = 2*pi*freq*t.*multiplier;
d_omega_t = diff(omega_t);
plot(d_omega_t);
```

If `d_omega_t` becomes greater than pi, you know you have an aliasing problem- you need at least two points per cycle to reproduce a waveform faithfully (Nyquist theorem). This can be solved by using a higher sampling frequency (more points), or a lower frequency.

As it is, your multipliers of 1 and 4 look OK because the aliasing that is going on is constant - so you don't notice it is a problem.

**update**

I just ran the above with and without the `+1` in the time variable - and it makes a big difference. The delta between two adjacent values is

```
2*pi*freq*(1 + t(n) - t(n-1)) * (mult(n) - mult(n-1))
2*pi*freq*(mult(n) - mult(n-1) + (t(n)-t(n-1)) * (mult(n)-mult(n-1))
```

This is a very large value because 2*pi*freq*(multi(n)-mult(n-1)) is a very large value.

When you leave out the `+1` and do

```
t = linspace(0, 4E-7, 1001);
multiplier = linspace(1,2,1001).^-2;
```

things behave themselves as expected - the plot ends up looking like:

[image]

Comment: So I believe I am sampling at 2.5 GHz, and the signal I am trying to create should start at 700 MHz and decay to say 300 MHz.  So at worst I should be sampling at 3-4 more then the wave I am trying to create?

Comment: See my updated answer - the delta in the value is much larger than you think because of the `+1` you have in the time variable. It took me a minute to convince myself that this made a very big difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Ahhhh, im still trying to understand whats happening but thanks for your insight, I got it to work better by dropping my start time to t = 0

Answer (score 2):

```
t = 0:0.0001:2*pi;
l = linspace(1,4,numel(t)).^2;
s = sin(t.*l);
figure,plot(t,fliplr(s)),axis tight
```

Produces the plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for some reason just changing my starting time value seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: That is great to hear!

Answer (score 2):

Found an appropriate answer here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217746-implementing-a-sine-wave-with-linearly-changing-frequency?s_tid=mwa_osa_a

"the formula:

```
 sin( 2*pi*f(t)*t )
```

does not result in the desired sine wave with time-varying frequency. Rather the appropriate formula would use, instead of f(t)*t, the integral between 0 and t of f(t):

```
 sin( 2*pi* ∫f(t)dt )
```

Only when f(t) is a constant f value, its integral is f*t, and the sine wave is the familiar sin(2*pi*f*t).

The rational for this is that the sinusoid frequency is the rate-of-change / derivative of the sinusoid phase. If you are given a desired frequency profile f(t) you need to integrate that to compute the desired sinusoid phase (up to a constant additive term), from which you can then compute your desired waveform.

(...)

Using sin(2*pi*f(t)*t) instead of sin(2*pi*∫f(t)dt) is not really an uncommon mistake at all when building frequency-modulated signals. This is aggravated by the fact that, when f(t) is a polynomial function, the former leads to an "almost correct-looking" solution. Trying instead a non-polynomial function (e.g. f(t)=2+sin(t), a frequency modulated tone oscillating between 1Hz and 3Hz) one is able to see the differences between the two methods quite more clearly."

(Alfonso Nieto-Castanon)

That solved the issue for me, while I was trying to create a linearly increasing frequency sinusoidal function, to model a variable frequency converter (V/F control) up ramp and was geting the double of the frequency in the end of the ramp.

I was using this function

```
 V(ctrl)*V(pk)*cos(v(w_ctrl)*time + 0*3.14159/180); (i)
```

where:

```
 v(w_ctrl) = 377 * V(ctrl); (ii)
```

and

```
 V(pk) = 180; (iii)

 V(ctrl) = 1*time; for time = 0...1 and V(ctrl) = 1; for time > 1 (iv)
```

so that the formula (i) reduced to:

```
 V(ctrl)*180*cos(377*time^2 + 0*3.14159/180); for time = 0...1 (v)
```

and the result could be seen in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXFQh.png).

Then I used the integral of the function v(w_ctrl), without the 'time' variable:

```
 V(ctrl)*V(pk)*cos(v(int_w_ctrl) + 0*3.14159/180); (vi)
```

wich was, actually, the function

```
 V(ctrl)*V(pk)*cos( (377*time^2)/2 + 0*3.14159/180); for time = 0...1 (vii)
```

which lead to the appropriate result, as can be seen in figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr7Xk.png).

The program I was using was Multisim 14, and the circuit can be seen in figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIgLf.png).

[Variable frequency up ramp - without integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXFQh.png)

[Variable frequency up ramp - with integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr7Xk.png)

[Simulation Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIgLf.png)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate signal with variable frequency you have to keep phase angle, therefore it would be best to do something like:

a[n+1] = a[n] + 2 * pi * f(t)

where a is phase of sine wave at sample n, f(t) is you changing frequency. Then the sine wave can be generated easily: sin(a)

matlab code for frequency going from 1 Hz to 4 Hz, in 2 seconds:

```
Ts = 0.0001;
t = 0:Ts:2;
f = linspace(1, 4, length(t));
d_a = 2 * pi * f * Ts;
a = cumsum(d_a) % + initial angle if you like
res = sin(a);
plot(t, res)
```